# How to Use json response hard coded in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

how can i use this json response hardcoded in the flutter screen and use that to retrieve list of country objects so i can use that list as list items for a dropdown.
I have the json response at hand and just want to use it hardcoded in my dart file.

***My Json Response***

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "AF",
    "dial_code": "+93",
    "name": "افغانستان"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "AX",
    "dial_code": "+358",
    "name": "Åland"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "code": "AL",
    "dial_code": "+355",
    "name": "Shqipëria"
  },
  ...
]
```

What i did so far is used this Future method to retrieve the country objects as a list and return it. here's my snippet.

```
List<CountryModel> _countryList = new List<CountryModel>();

  Future<List<CountryModel>> _fetchCountries() async {
    //
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    pr.show();

    String jsonString = '''[
    {
      "id": 1,
    "code": "AF",
    "dial_code": "+93",
    "name": "افغانستان"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "AX",
    "dial_code": "+358",
    "name": "Åland"
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "code": "AL",
    "dial_code": "+355",
    "name": "Shqipëria"
    },
]
    ''';

    http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      _countryList = countryModelFromJson(response.body);
      pr.hide();
      return _countryList;
      // return countryModelFromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      pr.hide();
      // _showSnackbar(, clr)
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

When i try this it gives me this error which i don't know how to solve.

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (string): Contains invalid characters.: "    {\n
```

how can achieve what i need above and fix this?

After a little bit of research I found this solution. It was a matter of unicode encoding for characters.

Add the below snippet inside the response ()

```
headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }
```

***Solution***

```
http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200, headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing comma in your json file:

```
String jsonString = '''[
    {
      "id": 1,
    "code": "AF",
    "dial_code": "+93",
    "name": "افغانستان"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "AX",
    "dial_code": "+358",
    "name": "Åland"
    },
    {
    "id": 3,
    "code": "AL",
    "dial_code": "+355",
    "name": "Shqipëria"
    }
]
    ''';
```

after the last object in the array.

Comment: in my full json code. at the final object there is no comma at all. I putted '...' to mimic that there's more.

Answer (score 0):

Please validate your JSON using any [json validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) before using in the code.

**Loading JSON from file**

```
String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
```

**Working prototype**

```
  String json = '''[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "AF",
    "dial_code": "+93",
    "name": "افغانستان"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "AX",
    "dial_code": "+358",
    "name": "Åland"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "code": "AL",
    "dial_code": "+355",
    "name": "Shqipëria"
  }
]''';

  List<Map<String,dynamic>> user = List<Map<String,dynamic>>.from(jsonDecode(json)).toList();
  print(user[1]); // {id: 2, code: AX, dial_code: +358, name: Åland}
```

Comment: can i save this json in a .json file and use it to do the above ? if so how can i do that?

Comment: thank you towhid, that works well. and though i get this error "Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (string): Contains invalid characters.:"

Comment: did you validate the json?

Comment: yes i did so, it still gives that error. maybe some of the countries are inserted in their local langauge. if so how can i solve this?

Comment: local language should not be a problem here. can you share the JSON file?